# A specific case of Le Cam's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

I was wondering if any of you folks could help me with this statistics problem. I need to show the two following inequalities:

\begin{align}
R_n (H) &: = \underset{\hat{f}}{\inf}\underset{f\in H}{\sup} E_f [(\hat{f}(y_0) - f(y_0))^2] 
\\&\geq \frac{1}{4} \underset{f_0 , f_1 \in H}{\sup} (f_0(y_0) - f_1(y_0))^2 . \int_{R^n} \min(p_{f_0}^n(y) ,p_{f_1}^n(y))\,dy
\end{align}
and
$$\int_{R^n} \min(p_{f_0}^n(y) ,p_{f_1}^n(y))dy \geq \exp\left\{\frac{-1}{4\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (f_0(x_i) - f_1(x_i))^2 \right\}$$
where we observe $Y_1 , ..., Y_n$ avec $Y_i \sim N(f(x_i) , \sigma ^2)$ with $x_i = \frac{i-1/2}{n}$. We note $\mathbf{Y}_n := (Y_1 , ..., Y_n)$ the observation and $p_{f}^n$ its density.
Here on assume that $\sigma ^2$ is known and $f:[0,1] \to R$ is unknown.
But for simplification we want just to estimate $f(y_0)$ avec $y_0 \in(0,1)$.
Thank you for your help